# React using CSS positioning with different components

Tags: css, reactjs, css-position

I'm trying to set up a landing page with a hero image as the background. I'm attempting to have two columns next to each other around the center of the screen. My plan was to use the **body tag** in **CSS** to set the `background-image` and set `position: relative` so that I could later use `position: absolute` for the columns with text in them to be in the center of the image/screen. However, I'm using React and I used the **index.js** component to set it to relative and to set the background and I then added a **Home component** That will contain the rest of the landing page, beginning with the two columns that must be set with `position absolute`.

In index.js styles component

```
body{
    background-image: url(../src/assets/HeroImage.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}
```

In Home styles component

```
.heroimage-text-container{
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

What happens by trying it this way is that the heroimage-text-container disappears when the position is set to absolute. I know this would not be happening if this was all within the same component so I'm hoping someone here could help me fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use flex box in this case. Absolute using the same class it will be overlapped because they will have the same properties.

```
body {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506716442075-1e2e0e5b1256?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1343&q=80");
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.heroimage-text-container {
  background-color: red;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Take a look at the sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-tdd-d39oc

Comment: If you want to use absolute to position your div exactly in the middle, try this: 
`.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  /*display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;*/
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.heroimage-text-container {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
`